# php reload page with diffrent parameter in the url using php_self

Tags: php

how to reload the same page with different parameters. coz i'm new to php so this way came into my mind. but it is giving the error header already sent..
here is the idea

```
//some script and at the last page   
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page=$_GET['page'];
    $page++;
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'page='.$page);
} else
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'page=1');
```

i'm new any suggestion will be appriciated

Answer (score 5):

So, you have to just correct the error you've got.
This error is the source of the most popular question on the Stackoverflow by the way.
thus, you will find plenty of the comprehensive answers.

Your way of the reloading is correct though.

I am only afraid it can become an infinite loop. What is the condition for this code to execute?

Comment: But searching for "headers already sent" is pretty difficult. I think you might be asking an awful lot!

Comment: ohhh i got one error that this will become infinite loop.. i was just asking about logic i used to reload the page again...

Comment: @Natasha Well, you need to explain what is the logic for the page reload. Why do you increment your page?

Comment: actually i'm fetching some data from a website that are offering data in chunks by hitting that page with different parameters  `code //geting data from website
if(isset($_GET['page']))
$string=get_content('http://abc.com/v1/getrealtimelocaldeals?key='.$key.'&page='.$page);
else
$string=get_content('http://abc.com/v1/getrealtimelocaldeals?key='.$key);`code

Comment: @yourCommonSense any different idea about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

use some sort of break condition otherwise it will go into infinite loop.. just incrementing and reloading page again and again..
    something like that

```
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page=$_GET['page'];
        $page++;
if(!$page>=50)
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'page='.$page);
    } else
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'page=1');
```